# Trying to create a Quickbooks Online Journal Entry using Devart dotConnect for Quickbooks

Tags: json, entity-framework, quickbooks, devart

I'm using a dotConnect for Quickbooks utility from Devart to create some General Journal Entries in Quickbooks Online using C# and Entity Framework.  (dotConnect for Quickbooks is version 1.10 and Entity Framework is version 6)

I found an article on Devart's forum: [forum link](https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=35364)
that suggested this isn't your normal Entity Framework walk in the park.

Support suggested, to the OP, assembling the entry as Json and assigning it to the JournalEntry.Line property.

When I do this it throws an error:
*"Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.g' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.o'"*

when hitting the ...SaveChanegs() method.  Querying Google for that error turned up nothing.  Has anyone come across this before?

So far I've tried:

- using an array of objects rather than a list of objects
- using Microsoft's Json serializer

Thanks!

Here's the code:
'''

```
            QuickbooksEntities contextQuickbooks = new QuickbooksEntities();
            JournalEntry je = new JournalEntry();

            //Query to the the QBO Account objects for our known AcctNum values
            Account creditAccount = contextQuickbooks.Accounts.Where(x => x.AcctNum == "4060-1").FirstOrDefault();
            Account debitAccount = contextQuickbooks.Accounts.Where(x => x.AcctNum == "1111").FirstOrDefault();

            // Build the credit and debit objects
            JournalEntryLineItem creditLine = new JournalEntryLineItem();
            creditLine.LineId = "0";
            creditLine.JournalEntryLineDetail_AccountRefId = creditAccount.Id;
            creditLine.JournalEntryLineDetail_AccountRefName = creditAccount.Name;
            creditLine.JournalEntryLineDetail_PostingType = "Credit";
            creditLine.DetailType = "JournalEntryLineDetail";
            creditLine.Amount = (decimal)3;
            
            JournalEntryLineItem debitLine = new JournalEntryLineItem();
            debitLine.LineId = "1";
            debitLine.JournalEntryLineDetail_AccountRefId = debitAccount.Id;
            debitLine.JournalEntryLineDetail_AccountRefName = debitAccount.Name;
            debitLine.JournalEntryLineDetail_PostingType = "Debit";
            debitLine.DetailType = "JournalEntryLineDetail";
            debitLine.Amount = (decimal)3;


            // Add the line items to a list
            List<JournalEntryLineItem> lines = new List<JournalEntryLineItem>();
            lines.Add(creditLine);
            lines.Add(debitLine);
            // Convert the list of line item objects to json
            var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lines);

            //JournalEntry journalEntry = new JournalEntry();
            je.TxnDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            je.CurrencyRefId = "USD";

            // Pass the json string to the JournalEntry.Line property
            je.Line = json;
            
            // The Entity Framework magic
            contextQuickbooks.JournalEntries.Add(je);
            contextQuickbooks.SaveChanges();
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

The bug with serializing empty values of the LinkedTxn field in the JournalEntryLineItem object is fixed in dotConnect for QuickBooks v1.10.1351.

The JSON (Newtonsoft.Json, Microsoft.Text.Json) and YAML (YamlDotNet) serializations are supported in EF Core (via EF Core template) and EF6 (via DbContext template) in v1.10.1375.

Refer to https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/quickbooks/revision_history.html.